# Batch file : copy file in subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I want to know that can be possible as below

Folder 1

```
   - sub folder(20180218-1100)
                 sub folderA => 1.txt
                 sub folderB => 1.txt
   - sub folder(20180218-1112)
                 sub folderA => 2.txt
                 sub folderB => 2.txt
```

want to copy file 1.txt and 2.txt on subfolderA of folder(20180218-1100) and sub folder(20180218-1112) 
so there are many subfolders(yyyymmdd-hhmm) of every time when I'm getting file

i'm try command
 for /R ".\1*" %%f in (*.txt) do xcopy /s %%f ".\"

Many Thanks

Comment: NO, it's absolutely impossible! Windows will not accept the colon character, **`:`**, in directory names.

Comment: many thanks,so sorry i'm explain wrong  sub folder(ddmmyyyy-hhmmss) sush as folder test_170216-220600

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48838339/edit), to clarify by providing your real information then!